# Python : Redirecting subprocess Popen stdout to log file

Tags: python, scala, logging, subprocess

I have a python process running, having a logger object configured to print logs in a log file.

Now, I am trying to call a `scala` script through this `python` process, by using `subprocess` module of Python.

```
subprocess.Popen(scala_run_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The issue is, whenever the python process exits, it hangs the shell, which comes to life only after explicitly running `stty sane` command. My guess is that it is caused because the scala script outputs to shell and hence the shell hangs, because of its stdout [something in its stdout causes the shell to lose its sanity].

For the same reason, I wanted to try to put the output of scala run script to be captured in my default log file, which does not seem to be happening using multiple ways.

So, **the query boils down to**, how to the get the `stdout` output of shell command ran through `subprocess` module in a log file. Even if there is a better way to achieve this instead of `subprocess, run`, I would love to know the ideas.

The current state of code looks like this.

```
__echo_command = 'echo ":load %s"' 
__spark_console_command = 'spark;' 
def run_scala_script(self, script): 
     echo_command = self.__echo_command % script 
     spark_console_command = self.__spark_console_command 
     echo_result = subprocess.run(echo_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
     result = subprocess.run(spark_console_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, input=echo_result.stdout) 
     logger.info('Scala script %s completed successfully' % script) 
     logger.info(result.stdout)
```

Comment: Try removing `shell=True`?

Comment: It does not even run if I remove this parameter, it fails with FileNotFoundError

Comment: You should remove `shell=True` and debug the `FileNotFoundError`. Are you passing the full path to the executable? Show us the actual content of your command.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
```

followed by

```
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

and then `stdout` and `stderr` will contain the output bytes from the subprocess' output streams. You can then log the `stdout` value.